# Nginx redirects

Tags: nginx, redirect

Let's say i have a virtual host in Nginx wtih name `www.domain.com` and root directory named `public`. Inside public i have 2 dirs `dir1` and `dir2`. How i redirect the request to www.domain.com to `dir1`?
I know it's a simple question, but i am new to nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to redirect visitors from www.domain.com to www.domain.com/dir1 ?

Then you can use a [rewrite statement](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) to rewrite. When you include http:// or https:// in the rewrite it will redirect visitors.

```
rewrite http://www.domain.com/(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1;
```

If you just want to use dir1 to serve content from, you can use [alias](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule), or you can rewrite without http:// like this:

```
rewrite / /dir1/;
```